# передача параметров css файла в скрипт php

Tags: css

```
<?php
echo "css entered value: ";
echo '$fname','$lname','$country';
?>
```

PHP не показывает значения переданные в броузер через css, что в скрипте не так?
[вот архив на с исходниками.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5jig5E9hRMwb3dUZFVHWmdOR00)
передача параметров css файла в скрипт php.
[image: броузер показывает]

Comment: Простите, а при чём тут css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить значения из формы, отправленной методом `GET` (как в вопросе), надо использовать [суперглобальный массив](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php) `$_GET`.

Таким образом:

```
$firstName = $_GET['firstname'];
```

или, с проверкой на наличие:

```
$firstName = isset($_GET['firstname']) ? $_GET['firstname'] : null; // что угодно
```

или, с проверкой на наличие в `PHP7`:

```
$firstName = $_GET['firstname'] ?? null;
```

*Интересный вопрос, интересные ответы..*

Answer (score 1):

Ваш php никак не определяет `$fname`, `$lname` и `$country` перед тем, как вывести их значения.

Если поставить двойные кавычки вместо одинарных, то должно получиться просто `css entered value:` без продолжения.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '$fname','$lname','$country';
```

замени на

```
echo $fname.$lname.$country;
```

Comment: echo $fname.$lname.$country; ничего не поменяло, спасибо и на том.

Comment: Странно, компа под рукой нет, должно работать. А попробуй так print($fname.$any);

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$fname","$lname","$country";
```

Просто замените одинарные кавычки на двойные. И прочитайте в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php), чем в PHP отличается обработка строк в одинарных и двойных кавычках.

Answer (score 0):

[передача значения из css в php скрипт](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5jig5E9hRMwZGhHZTNuVlUxdE0)
[image: спасибо]